# Why do developers write CSS animation rule without prefix?

Tags: css, browser, css-animations

I wanted to ask that as every browser has its prefix for animation then why developers write a property without any prefix. Look at this example taken from [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp):

```
div {
    -ms-transform: scale(0.5,0.5); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5,0.5); /* Safari */
    transform: scale(0.5,0.5);
}
```

Why does the second last line exist?

Comment: The prefixes exist as a means of providing a preview to a feature that is still standardizing in CSS and/or not stable. The un-prefixed version is considered the standard CSS property. See [Vendor Prefix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix).

Comment: @MarcBaumbach But the prefixed and unprefixed properties are the same.

Comment: That's because the prefixed properties ended up matching exactly like the standardized one. There are other examples where that hasn't been the case. Look up the vendor prefixes and resulting standard for flexbox, for example. Some vendor prefixes differ in syntax, some do not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So not every modern browser requires prefixes. Infact the CSS community want to move away from them as a general consensus, as they are essentially a reminiscent of the browser wars. In some use cases, they can be helpful. Your example allows support for IE9, whereas IE10+ wont require this prefix.

Some developers don't want to support legacy browsers, some do. It's that simple. All depends on your needs.

Comment: So if I want to write code for most of the browsers then I should include the unprefixed version as well

Comment: Always include the unprefixed version if it exists. The decision to include the vendor prefixes is dependent on which browser versions you want to support. There are tools out there to help you automatically prefix too, e.g., [Autoprefixer](https://css-tricks.com/autoprefixer/).

Comment: And always include the unprefixed version last.

Comment: @Arjun, browsers will ignore properties they don't understand and the last understood property "wins". Order wouldn't matter if browser vendors removed the prefixed properties when they implemented the standards-compliant un-prefixed properties, but often they don't for a while, so if you list the prefixed property last, the non-standard behavior will "win". By listing the standards-compliant property last, you are future-proofing your code.

Comment: Also you forgot to mention in your answer: most dev use some kind of post-processor that may automatically add vendor prefixes, such as postcss.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm off topic, but I would argue that many projects nowadays use CSS preprocessors and/or some kind of building tool (like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org), [gulp](http://gulpjs.com) or [CodeKit](https://codekitapp.com)) to compile development CSS into production-ready code.

All these task managers allow you to write your code without thinking about vendor prefixes, and delegate most of the browser support headaches to plugins like [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer).